# Parsing the result of a command in a Linux bash script

Tags: linux, bash, parsing

I am writing a small bash script in Linux to control Pulseaudio inputs/outputs.

What I want to do is to route all sink-inputs, except one, into one or another sink. The sink-input I don't want to route is this one:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/fonction $ pactl list sink-inputs
Sink Input #36062
    Driver: protocol-native.c
    Owner Module: 2
    Client: 198
    Sink: 2
    Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    Channel Map: front-left,front-right
    Format: pcm, format.sample_format = "\"s16le\""  format.rate = "44100"  format.channels = "2"  format.channel_map = "\"front-left,front-right\""
    Corked: no
    Mute: no
    Volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
            balance 0.00
    Buffer Latency: 120000 usec
    Sink Latency: 236349 usec
    Resample method: n/a
    Properties:
        media.name = "ALSA Playback"
        application.name = "ALSA plug-in [snapclient]"
        native-protocol.peer = "UNIX socket client"
        native-protocol.version = "32"
        application.process.id = "539"
        application.process.user = "snapclient"
        application.process.host = "raspberrypi"
        application.process.binary = "snapclient"
        application.language = "C"
        application.process.machine_id = "69e523231bb44f2e926a758a63cbb5b1"
        module-stream-restore.id = "sink-input-by-application-name:ALSA plug-in [snapclient]"
```

To move a sink-input to another sink I need to use this command:

```
pactl move-sink-input <sink-input id> <sink id>
```

So I have to parse the result of the first command to get the `Sink Input #ID` (contained in the first line) but I have to use a condition to check if `module-stream-restore.id` (last line) is really what I want to route.

I'd need something like:

```
if [ <last line> = 'sink-input name I need' ] 
then
  pactl move-sink-input <id from first line> <my sink name>
fi
```

I just don't know how to parse the command to get BOTH information.

Right now, I am able to get only the last line, or only the #ID.

```
 pactl list short sink-inputs|while read stream; do
    streamId=$(echo $stream )
    id=$(echo pactl list sink-inputs | grep module-stream-restore.id | grep -o '".*"' |sed 's/"//g')

    if [ "$streamId" != 'sink-input-by-application-name:ALSA plug-in [snapclient]' ]
    then
        pactl move-sink-input "$streamId" Snapcast
    fi
```

How do I proceed to parse the result of `pactl list sink-inputs` so I can read  two elements, not just one, in each "block" (aka, each sink-input) of the result of that command in a bash script?

Comment: Why dont you save the sink input number in a variable?

Comment: You can get ther first line and the last line with `head -n1` and `tail -n1` or `sed '1!d'` and `sed '$!d'`

Comment: @Nifle, the sink-input number could change anytime.

Comment: @Paulo, I'll give it a try tonight. It might be just what I need.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that variables set in the `do` loop are not maintained from one pass to the next.

The simple solution is to save the list output to a temporary file, then scan it twice:-

```
pactl list short sink-inputs >temp.lst
streamId=$(sed -n 's/^Sink Input #\(.*\)$/\1/p' <temp.lst)
id=$(sed -n 's/.*module-stream-restore.id = "\(.*\)"$/\1/p' <temp.lst)
rm temp.lst
```

You now have the two variables you need both set. It's not a very elegant solution, but it's straightforward and easy to understand and maintain. Note that I have used `sed` to perform the `grep` functions: for a guide to how this works, see [here](http://www.grymoire.com/unix/sed.html).

However, you can avoid the temporary file with a more convoluted solution:-

```
Ids="$(pactl list short sink-inputs | \
       sed -n -e 's/^Sink Input #\(.*\)$/\1/p' \
              -e 's/.*module-stream-restore.id = "\(.*\)"$/\1/p')"
```

You now have both variables in `Ids`, separated by a new-line: you can split them with:-

```
streamId="${Ids%$'\n'*}"
Id="${Ids#*$'\n'}"
```

If you don't like temporary variables either, you can use `Id` instead of `Ids`!

I have tested this by copying your list output and using this instead of a real `pactl` command, so it should all work with a live command.

Answer (score 2):

The concept:

1. Invoke `pactl …` with `LC_ALL=C` set to avoid localized output (you apparently don't need this but in general case people do).
2. Use `egrep` to discard irrelevant lines. You want to get pairs of lines that look like this:

   ```
   Sink Input #12345
           module-stream-restore.id = "whatever"
   ```
3. Assuming the lines go in pairs, `read` them two by two with proper `IFS` (`#` for the first line in a pair, `=` for the second) to extract relevant data. Use dummy variables for parts you don't need.
4. Work with extracted data. Note that `IFS='='` for the second line in a pair  will extract everything after the `=`, i.e. the adjacent space and double quotes as well. This is why in the code (below) I match against `' "sink-… [snapclient]"'`, not just `'sink-… [snapclient]'`.

The code:

```
LC_ALL=C pactl list sink-inputs |
egrep "^Sink Input #|module-stream-restore.id = " |
while IFS='#' read dummy id && IFS='=' read dummy restid; do
 if [ "$restid" = ' "sink-input-by-application-name:ALSA plug-in [snapclient]"' ] ; then
  printf 'Match for ID %s.\n' "$id"
  # do something
 else
  printf 'No match for ID %s.\n' "$id"
  # do something else
 fi
done
```